# How to capture (or log) the data of the Response object in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, logging

I need to capture de sended data. I know how to set a middleware and capture the request and the response header.

I'm asking for capture the sent data.

I'm trying this:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

var onFinished = require('on-finished')

app.listen(3000);

function logRes(res){
    console.log('* captured response *')
    console.log(res._header)
    console.log(res.statusCode)
    console.log(res.statusMessage)
    console.log(res.body)  // THIS DOES NOT WORKS!
}

app.use(function(req,res,next){
    onFinished(res, function (err, res) {
        logRes(res)
    })
    console.log('= captured request =');
    console.log(req.method)
    console.log(req.path)
    console.log(req.query)
    next();
});

app.get('/example',function(req,res){
    res.header('Content-Type','text/plain');
    res.end('example data');
});
```

Can any says to me how to look at the sent data in the line with the `// THIS DOES NOT WORKS!` comment?

Answer (score -3):

You first need to include the third party middleware `body-parser`:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000);

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));

app.use(function(req,res,next) {
    console.log('= captured request =');
    console.log(req.method);
    console.log(req.path);
    console.log(req.query);
    console.log(req.body);
    next();
});

app.get('/example',function(req,res) {
    res.header('Content-Type','text/plain');
    res.end('example data');
});
```

Check the repo and documentation [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser).

Comment: `var bodyParser = require('body-parser')` does not resolve the problem. I try your code. I put in Chrome `http://localhost:3000/example` and I obtain `undefined` in the `console.log(res.body)` line. I supouse that `body-parse` is for parse the request, not to show the captured **response**

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer Obviously `bodyParser` is to parse the request, the data that you sent is part of the body request so to catch it you need to retrieve it from `req` object (instead of res).

Comment: your post and your comment does not answer my question. How to see the sended data?. I try your edited example. In the log it does not apears "example data". Do you see it?. I'm trying to ask how to see all the data sended to the client. The client receives "example data" (I see it in the navigator), but does not shows in the `console.log`

Comment: Ok I get it now. Clients also send data so "sent data" sounds ambiguous. I am not sure if is possible what you want. Can you explain why are you trying to do that? Maybe I can suggest you another alternative.

Comment: Two cases of use: (a) making statistics for debuging of all the data sended to the client. (b) capturing all javascripts and previos to send to the client and if it is IE8 replace ".catch" with "['catch']".

Comment: Answer does not answer the question. The user wants to know how to log the body of the response, not the inbound request.